# Multiple IF and AND statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

Thank you in advance for your answers. I have looked through the forum and have not found the right example /answers to match my problem. The problem seems to lie with the syntax:

The formula: 
`=IF(AND($A4=VAR!$A$2;ISBLANK($C4));$B4*VAR!$B$2;IF(AND($A4=VAR!$A$3;ISBLANK($C4));$B4*VAR!$B$2;IF(AND($A4=VAR!$A$4;ISBLANK($C4));$B4*VAR!$B$2;IF(AND($A4=VAR!$A$5;ISBLANK($C4));$B4*VAR!$B$2;IF(AND($A4=VAR!$A$6;ISBLANK($C4));$B4*VAR!$B$2;IF(AND($A4=VAR!$A$7;ISBLANK($C4));$B4*VAR!$B$2;C4))))))`

for the next service it is like this :

`=IF(AND($A4=VAR!$A$2;ISBLANK($D4));$B4*VAR!$B$3;IF(AND($A4=VAR!$A$3;ISBLANK($D4));$B4*VAR!$B$3;IF(AND($A4=VAR!$A$4;ISBLANK($D4));$B4*VAR!$B$3;IF(AND($A4=VAR!$A$5;ISBLANK($D4));$B4*VAR!$B$3;IF(AND($A4=VAR!$A$6;ISBLANK($D4));$B4*VAR!$B$3;IF(AND($A4=VAR!$A$7;ISBLANK($D4));$B4*VAR!$B$3;D4))))))`

Problem:  the formula seems to work from left to right not all field are updated.

The variables page looks like this :

I am trying to create a formula that verifies if there is a value in the BLUE part (column C to G on Input) if a number is found the " stand service % split is replaced by the input on the blue side.

This partly works however excel seems to diagree with my formula.

Thank you in advance for your assistance. Shame XLS sheets can not be uploaded. Best regards

Remy

You can find the [example sheet here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxsO5XwJqykYZFRPMWJna0FnLTg/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: I tried locating your picture link in your original post but didn't find it. Post the link so I or somebody else can include it in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Even with your example spreadsheet on google drive it is very difficult to work out what you're trying to do here.

Nevertheless, I think that this is close:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($A4,VAR!$A$2:$A$7,0))),VLOOKUP($A4,VAR!$A$2:$B$7,2,FALSE)*$B4,C4)
```

Have a play with that and see if it works for you.

I would also recommend that you learn to use excel in R1C1 mode rather than A1. Once you get used to it is in infinitely better for debugging spreadsheets.

I find this far more readable:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(RC1,VAR!R2C1:R7C1,0))),VLOOKUP(RC1,VAR!R2C1:R7C2,2,FALSE)*RC2,RC[-6])
```